# Play 2.3 jshint disable on vendor js

Tags: playframework-2.3, sbt-web

I have several vendor minified js under app/assets. How can I disable jshint to process these files?

app/assets/js/vendor/angular-moment.min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add something like this to your `build.sbt`:

```
excludeFilter in (Assets, JshintKeys.jshint) := "*.min.js"
```

Comment: This is what I am using: excludeFilter in rjs := GlobFilter("*.min.js").